# Why memory addresses are even numbers?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory

After noticing in the VS debugger that memory adresses are usually even numbers I tried out the following program (MS Visual Studio 2012)

```
struct noise {
    int data[3];
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   
    std::vector<noise*> vn; 
    std::vector<std::complex<double>*> vv;

    for (int i(0); i < 90000; ++i) {
        std::complex<double> *cur = new std::complex<double>(1, 1);
        assert( ! ((int)cur&1) ); // assert if adress is not even
        vv.push_back(cur);
        if ( ! (i% (rand()%5 + 1)) ) vn.push_back(new noise);
    }

    for (std::size_t i(0), ie(vv.size()); i < ie; ++i) { delete vv[i]; }
    for (std::size_t i(0), ie(vn.size()); i < ie; ++i) { delete vn[i]; }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

It never asserts! How so? Is there a way to make it assert? Are there any uses for this as a sideffect?

Comment: I think from 16-bit systems onwards, compilers would rather pad one byte than take the speed penalty for odd memory adresses.

Comment: It gets a bit more interesting.  Your addresses will most commonly be multiples of 4 or 8 -- and often even 16, if you're just seeing what `new` and `malloc` give you.  You may want to read a bit about alignment.

Comment: ... and then in some platforms the hardware cannot even access unaligned types

Comment: @mbratch Not if he looks at the start addresses of `char` arrays, only some elements of such arrays are at odd (or otherwise non-aligned) addresses. The array as a whole is most likely allocated through some interface which guarantees a certain minimum alignment (like `malloc` does).

Comment: @mbratch Ignoring the fact that there is no array being allocated in OP's code, the loop is repeatedly allocating new objects, not iterating over anything.

Comment: @delnan yes, I agree. Sorry I wasn't looking at it closely enough.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Processors (and thus, compilers) generally like data to be "[aligned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)" to a higher granularity than bytes. For example, since a 32-bit processor deals with numbers in 32-bit chunks, and not 8-bit chunks, it's more efficient for things to be aligned on 32-bit (4 byte) boundaries. In fact, some processors even *require* a certain level of alignment.

There are lots of other reasons for alignment, such as preventing a word from spanning across multiple memory pages. Compilers will often insert padding inside data structures so that each member of the structure is aligned to a certain multiple (usually powers of 2). Most compilers also allow you to change the alignment settings (using a `#pragma`).